# Sockets: Setting up a client and server

Tags: ios11, swift4

I want to create a toy example with a client and an echo server.

Is there a way for an iOS app running in the Simulator to connect to a server running on my Macbook?  Or, is there something similar to localhost in iOS?  For instance, can I run a client and a server in two different background threads? I actually tried that, but the server doesn't receive any data from the client:

```
//This uses SwiftSocket installed with Cocoapods: 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

        let udpServer = UDPServer(address: "localhost", port:12033)
        var count = 1

        while true {
            print("Server about to recv() \(count)")

            let(data, sender, port) = udpServer.recv(6)
            print("data: \(data)\nsender: \(sender)\nport: \(port)\n\n")

            if let data = data {
                    print("Server received: \(data) from \(sender) on port \(port)")
            }

            sleep(1)
            count += 1

        }

    }

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        let udpClient = UDPClient(address: "localhost", port: 12033)

        switch udpClient.send(string: "Hello\n") {
        case .success:
            print("Client sent message to server.")
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Client failed to send message to server: \(error)")
        }

        udpClient.close()
    }


}

--output:--

Server about to recv() 1
Client sent message to server.
data: nil
sender: no ip
port: 0


Server about to recv() 2
data: nil
sender: no ip
port: 0


Server about to recv() 3
data: nil
sender: no ip
port: 0


Server about to recv() 4
data: nil
sender: no ip
port: 0
```

I'm a little confused by the `recv()`.  Shouldn't that block?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the server will receive the data (and the `recv()` blocks), if I use `"127.0.0.1"` for the host string instead of `"localhost"`.

And, if I run a server on my Macbook that listens on `"127.0.0.1"` (and I get the ports to match in my iOS code and the server code!), then the server running on my Macbook receives the data from the iOS client.

One question I had was whether the `recv()` for a UDP socket needs to be the exact length of the data.  My results show that you can `recv()` in efficient chunks, and if the length of the data is shorter than the specified chunk, the `recv()` will read what is available, then return.

And if you are confused about whether you need to loop over a `recv()` to gather all the data that was in a `send()`, here is a [great post](https://serverfault.com/questions/534063/can-tcp-and-udp-packets-be-split-into-pieces) on the matter:

> Examples. Blocks of contiguous characters correspond to send() calls:
>
> TCP:
>
> ```
> Send: AA BBBB CCC DDDDDD E         Recv: A ABB B BCC CDDD DDDE
> ```
>
> All data sent is received in order, but not necessarily in the same
>   chunks.
>
> UDP:
>
> ```
> Send: AA BBBB CCC DDDDDD E         Recv: CCC AA E
> ```
>
> Data is not necessarily in the same order, and not necessarily
>   received at all, but messages are preserved in their entirety.

With TCP, you need to loop over the `recv()` until you find the marker that indicates the end of the data you are trying to read e.g. a newline, a special sequence of characters, or maybe the blank string that is returned by `recv()` when the socket is closed by the sender.

With UDP, one `recv()` will read all the data in a `send()`.